# Qt5 and CMAKE_AUTORCC

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am attempting to port an existing project using Qt to use cmake. The project has (a few) `ui` and (one) `qrc` files. In the CMakeLists.txt, if I use:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
```

and generate a Visual Studio (2015) project, it has a pre-build step, generating the sources from the `ui` files, and adding those generated files to the VS project. However, if I include the `qrc` file in the project sources, and then set:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
```

The generated project no longer has the pre-build step. It does contain the corresponding `qrc.cpp` file. However, when the project build, it fails because the file doesn't exist, and doesn't get generated. I've also tried setting `CMAKE_AUTORCC` to `OFF`, and using `QT5_ADD_RESOURCES`. That doesn't remove the `ui` prebuild step, but doesn't add the `qrc.cpp` to the project.

I'm using Qt 5.6.0 and cmake 3.5.2.

Comment: It is unclear from your description which build step is not being executed: uic or rcc. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get meaningful answers.

Comment: rcc never executes, using either method I described. If I use `CMAKE_AUTORCC OFF`, then uic will execute. If I use `CMAKE_AUTORCC ON`, then uic will not execute.

Comment: Have you setup "set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)"? Your files should be generated in current directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realize it's been almost 4 months, but I ran into the same exact problem just now, and read through your question. After looking through Qt doc on icons/qrc resource system, I have a working solution. I have all 3 settings in the same `CMakeLists.txt` file -- previously had the first two on:

```
set (CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set (CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set (CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
```

Then when you add your exe/dll, do thus:

```
addlibrary (${myDLL} SHARED ${mySRC_LIST} ${myQRC_LIST})
```

where, you guessed it, the new list of files `${myQRC_LIST}` contains the list of `.qrc` files. Voilà! My first try I had this result, which is very rare!

[image: File menu and toolbar]

Of course I could have combined my `.qrc` files into `${mySRC_LIST}` as well, but I like to keep my lists homogeneous. Whatever you do, please read through [Qt Resource Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) so that the icons get included properly. Hope this helps.